# git-lfs speeding up checkout

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I want to work with git-lfs. So I cloned my current repository, created a branch and pushed some files:

```
git clone <url>
git checkout -b lfs-test
git lfs install
git lfs track "*.log"
mkdir data
mkfile -n 1g data/test.log
git add . && git commit -m "test" && git push --set-upstream origin test && git push
```

Works so far but when I switch from master to lfs-test branch it works different than expected because [Speeding up pulls](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs#speeding-up-pulls) has no effect on switching branches.

What I expect: download git lfs files as a batch (like described [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs#speeding-up-pulls))

- macos sierra
- git-lfs/2.2.1 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.8.3)
- git version 2.14.1
- newest Bitbucket LFS Media Adapter

Comment: What did you expect? Please be specific about what the question is here.

Comment: Just to confirm: is "origin" bitbucket.org?

Comment: @JimRedmond yes, it is

Comment: Temporary solution: `git lfs install --system --skip-smudge`. This disables automatically pull/clone lfs files on my host.